# Is there common database about drugs from around the world?

Tags: healthcare-data, database

Let's say I would like to find cheaper Chinese alternative or find a drug by an active substance (by Xylose Isomerase for instance). Is there any site that could help with that?

Comment: In [this answer](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/20290/mechanism-of-action-moa-of-medical-drugs/20291#20291), there are 4 examples of websites with comprehensive descriptions of drugs. They won't tell you the price, though. And when you are buying drugs online "from around the world", you may not know what exactly will you get (in sense of purity, safety, etc.). And sometimes you can find much simpler and cheaper solutions for a given problem. Just saying.

Comment: @Jan ok, thanks.